# Cross object duplicate rules

Tags: duplicate-management

I have object with few normal fields and formula field which needs to be checked for duplicate rule matching - the formula field is a just a field of another object. We can't add formula field to matching rules so I thought it would be a great idea to create cross object matching rule but it doesn't work correctly - it's like there is OR between the rules - if one of them is true duplicate rule fires. I'd like to create AND between them - when both rules are matching duplicate alert should fire. How to achieve this without Apex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured a solution to this problem.

I've created additional field which duplicates a value from formula field and used it in matching rule, then I've created before trigger which duplicates value from formula field.